# External Monitors not detected

Tags: multiple-monitors, bios, dell-xps, docking-station, thunderbolt

External Monitors not detected with Dell Thunderbolt TB16 Docking Station. I moved my computer and unhooked everything. When I plugged everything back in the external monitor did not come on. I tried dell software updates, Restarting the computer, shutting the lid. The power was on to the docking station. The monitor works plugged directly into the laptop no problem. When I restarted I'd get a low power warning that I was 60 out of 130 needed. Nothing changed. There's likely more to try. Usually you hear the ding and it works.

I Have this Docking station

https://www.cdw.com/product/Dell-Thunderbolt-Dock-TB16-Docking-Station/4503304?cm_cat=google&cm_ite=4503304&cm_pla=NA-NA-DELL_LA&cm_ven=acquirgy&ef_id=WMwdIQAAAFVt1VSc:20190319163810:s&ev_chn=shop&gclid=EAIaIQobChMItvnpiNKO4QIVyx-tBh2RTAKoEAQYBSABEgJWRvD_BwE&s_kwcid=AL!4223!3!198574006072!!!g!315899220420!

with a dell XPS 15 laptop

Comment: The linked content in your post is not available to people outside organisations based in the US.

Comment: @angelofdev Really? I can read it and I'm pretty sure the UK is not yet based in the US ...

Comment: @DavidPostill [https://imgur.com/a/lOpAkXs](https://imgur.com/a/lOpAkXs)

Comment: @angelofdev {shrug}. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did (the next day) that worked. My monitor shuts off after only a few seconds of not finding a source. So I unplugged my thunderbolt connection from the laptop and turned on the monitor. Then when the monitor was looking for source I plugged in the thunderbolt connection to the laptop. I heard the usual *Chime* and the monitor connected to the docking station came on.

Comment: Holy crap, that actually worked! And not just one monitor. I have three connected to the dock, none of them worked, I disconnected the dock from my computer, turned one monitor off, turned it back on, reconnected the dock while the monitor was searching for source and all three monitors came back up. I've tried everything and this, somehow, was the only thing that actually worked. Thank you!